# Register / Configure DataSource on demand in Micronaut - Data

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-data

I am building a framework for some multi tenant application and it needs some dynamism with respect to data sources.

I did check micronaut-data 3.9 and 4.0 rc builds and found that the team has introduced TenantDataSourceResolver and TenantSchemaResolver interfaces to dynamically select datasource / schema based on MultiTenant strategy.

However, it still requires all the datasources to be pre-registered via application.yml. In my case the new datasources may get added dynamically and hence the need of dynamic registration of DataSource beans.

I studied the code of micronaut-data and everything starts from DatasourceConfiguration and wired via  @EachProperty / @EachBean annotations till DefaultJdbcRepositoryOperations. Some of the beans (e.g. io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.DataSourceFactory#dataSource) are bound to @Context scope hence they are eager initialized and bound to the context.

Any help in this direction is appreciated. I really like micronaut-data but it feels lots of magic (especially for one who comes from Spring background) of compile time AOP and dynamic classes (generated via asm).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This was the only way I found to register and configure datasource on demand.

**In my case, I created a schedule to check if there are new configurations to update, checking if it is already in**

```
Collection<DatasourceConfiguration> beansOfType = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(DatasourceConfiguration.class);


// Class that contains database connection settings
@Getter
@Setter
public class DataBaseConfig {
    private String tenantId;
    private String host;
    private String port;
    private String user;
    private String pass;
    private String database;
}

// This class loads the BeanContext to register the new datasource configuration
@Singleton
public class MyFactory {
    private final BeanContext beanContext;
    public MyFactory(BeanContext beanContext) {
        this.beanContext = beanContext;
    }

    public void create(DatasourceConfiguration datasourceConfigurationd) {
        beanContext.registerSingleton(DatasourceConfiguration.class, datasourceConfiguration, Qualifiers.byName(datasourceConfigurationd.getName()));
    }
}

// connection to some service that returns the database connection settings
@Client("https://service.search.tenant/"))
public interface IClientTenant{
    @Get("/{tenantId}")
    DataBaseConfig get(String tenantId)
}



@Singleton
public class NewDataSources {

    private IClientTenant clientTenant;
    private MyFactory myFactory;
    public NewDataSources(IClientTenant clientTenant, MyFactory myFactory) {
        this.clientTenant = clientTenant;
        this.myFactory = myFactory;
    }


    public void addNewDatasourceConfiguration(String tenantId){
        var dc = clientTenant.get(tenantId);

        var url = String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://%s:%s;database=%s;TrustServerCertificate=True", dc.getHost(), dc.getPort(),dc.getDatabase());
        DatasourceConfiguration hikariConfig = new DatasourceConfiguration(dc.getTenantId());
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(url);
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        hikariConfig.setUsername(dc.getUser());
        hikariConfig.setPassword(dc.getPass());
        hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(2);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(8);
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(SECONDS.toMillis(15));
        hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(MINUTES.toMillis(2));
        hikariConfig.setValidationTimeout(SECONDS.toMillis(2));
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("select 1");
        hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(MINUTES.toMillis(30));
        hikariConfig.setPoolName(dc.getDatabase());

        myFactory.create(hikariConfig);
    }

}
```